# Where is the database of "Corpus Latinorum Et Mediaevalium Naturae Scriptorum", promised 10 years ago

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, text-corpus

Has anybody found the actual database of ["Corpus Latinorum Et Mediaevalium Naturae Scriptorum"](https://www.google.de/search?&q=Corpus%20Latinorum%20Et%20Mediaevalium%20Naturae%20Scriptorum) instead of just project notes? The descriptions look incredibly promising:

> CLEMENS, acronym for Corpus Latinorum Et Mediaevalium Naturae Scriptorum, is a new electronic archive of *excerpta* reporting environment-related data contained in the literary and epigraphic sources of classical Roman and Medieval age. The aim is to fill a gap in information about environmental disruptions or memorabilia that occurred in ancient times within the Mediterranean basin, and to verify whether any useful information has eluded our knowledge. One of the main purposes of the systematic gathering and cataloguing carried out by CLEMENS is to become an extensive easy-to-search tool, offering the scientific community complete annotated documentation of what is available inside ancient sources about the natural environment in the Mediterranean. This information, currently dispersed in a variety of publications that may be difficult to access, has often proven essential for hazard assessment in several areas of the former Roman empire. It also contributes significantly to the understanding of changes caused by environmental events over the centuries, and of their incidence on natural habitats and on cultural heritage. The analysis of such interconnections may lead to a much improved understanding of either natural environment, hazards and cultural setting, as shown by interdisciplinary investigations merging together science, archaeology and history or even myth.
>
> Considering the vast amount of documentation, the work is still far from completion. However, the encouraging preliminary results will soon be available on the web.

This citation is from 
[L. Piccardi & W. B. Masse: "Myth and Geology", The Geological Society: London, 2008, p 51–61.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jqs.1208/abstract)

"Soon" should be reached by now.

But where is it? Was it renamed, only in Italian, offline only, abandoned?

Comment: Most likely it never materialized. Just to be on the safe side, you could email the principal researcher(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty of asking directly to the authors, receiving this reply:

[image]

PS: the authors' email addresses are publicly available on their websites, so I think it should not be a problem to show it above. If you disagree, let me know.

Comment: Not the best news about that, but SE answer-wise it seems to not get much better than that. Thx.

Comment: Well, at least they're honest.